# Content writer not closed by transformer:

Tags: solr4, alfresco-webscripts

I am using alfresco-5.0.d and solr 4 everytime i am getting this error when solr is indexing a file.

> ERROR [content.transform.AbstractContentTransformer2]
>   [http-apr-8080-exec-9] Content writer not closed by transformer:
>   writer: ContentAccessor[
>   contentUrl=store://2017/7/4/7/25/b797706e-c02f-45a4-9e71-5db7fb4d5ad4.bin,
>   mimetype=text/plain, size=0, encoding=UTF-8, locale=en_US]
>   transformer: PdfBoxContentTransformer

can anyone tell me why i am getting this exception and anyways to fix it?

Comment: did you made any customization?

Comment: ya i made some changes in solr filter and redirecting the excecution flow

Comment: did this error was there before change?